# I want to move some stacks of a stacked bar plot to below the x axis but doing so breaks the order of the stacks

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a df with the percentage of students that got a grade in a test (from A to D) for several schools. This df has the following structure

```
str(DF)
'data.frame':   244 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ School: Factor w/ 61 levels 
 $ variable: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D"
 $ value   : num  22.4 29.8 16.7 35.1 23.6 ...
```

(the school column is  a factor so i can plot them in a specific order)

I am using the following ggplot 2 code to graph this data, this code  works perfectly to show the stacked bars in the correct order (A at the top and D at the bottom):

````
ggplot(DF, aes(x = School, y = -value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=paleta, labels = etiquetas)+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(value), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2, color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_sub(x, end = 20))```
````

I have tried many methods to move the percentage of students that got either a D or a C grade to below the x axis but whenever i do it the order of the stack breaks, usually the stack above the x axis flip so A is at the bottom and B is at the top.

Comment: I find it hard to follow what you mean. If you have negative values when variable is C or D they will stack in the negative direction, so perhaps try `aes(School, ifelse(variable %in% c("C", "D"), -value, value), fill = variable)`? Otherwise, please make your example reproducible so we can see what is actually going on.

Comment: Hi! thank you for the quick reply, i am sorry if i struggle to explain, i am relatively new to R and stackoverflow. 

I tried the code you recomended, it is something i tried before it still messes with the order of the stack. By adding the line you sent the level at the top of the stack for every school is now the percentage of students with B as a grade instead of A. so from top to bottom the stack now shows the percentage of students in B, A, C, D. I dont understand why only the top levels flip when i turn C and D into negative values. 

Again, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider calling an empty ggplot() with two filtered geom_bar()s

```
df <- data.frame(school = rep(c('Adams', "Berkley", "Canter"), 4), 
                 variable = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 3), 
                 value = c(5, 10, 20, 
                           55, 45, 50, 
                           20, 15, 20,  
                           20, 30, 10
                           )
                 ) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(
    variable %in% c('C', 'D') ~ -value, 
    TRUE ~ value
  )) %>% 
  mutate(variable = factor(variable, 
                           levels = c('A', 'B', 'D', 'C'))) %>% 
  arrange(school, variable)


ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df,value >= 0),
           mapping = aes(x = school, 
               y = value, 
               fill = variable), 
           stat="identity"
           ) +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df,value < 0),
           mapping = aes(x = school, 
               y = value, 
               fill = variable), 
           stat="identity",
           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  labs(fill = 'Grade')+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T))+
  scale_fill_manual(values =  c('#e57a3c', '#e2a331', '#22a783', '#3688c8'), #colors
                    breaks =  c('D', 'C', 'B','A'),
                    labels =  c('D', 'C', 'B','A'))
```

[image: sample]